# Aligning the header in LaTeX

Tags: letters, letterhead

How do I align the text to center in the header and the date , below the horizontal line,

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{headheight = 35pt}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{pecemblem}}\textsc{Pondicherry Engineering College\\ \textsc{Pillaichavady}\\ \textsc{Puducherry-605014}}} 
%\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[height=0.5in]{pecemblem}}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}%
    \begin{letter}{}%
        \opening{Dear Some Name,}
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{letter}%
\end{document}%
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once again, adjust the values of `headheight` and `top`, and `scale`.

Also, all lines with `\textsc` have to go inside the braces of `\fancyhead`

MWE

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{headheight=6cm,top=8cm}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[scale=1.2]{pecemblem}\\
\textsc{Pondicherry Engineering College}\\ \textsc{Pillaichavady}\\ \textsc{Puducherry-605014}}}
%\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[height=0.5in]{pecemblem}}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}%
    \begin{letter}{}%
        \opening{Dear Some Name,}
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{letter}%
\end{document}%
```

Output

[image]

Anyway, I would opt for a solution that does not involve headers, like this one:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[height=0.5in]{pecemblem}}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}%
    \begin{letter}{}%

        \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=1.2]{pecemblem}\\
        \textsc{Pondicherry Engineering College}\\
        \textsc{Pillaichavady}\\
        \textsc{Puducherry-605014}\\
        \hrulefill
        \end{center}

        \opening{Dear Some Name,}     
        \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{letter}%
\end{document}%
```

Output

[image]